# Strange vertical line at side of emacs window, while it maximized

Tags: linux, emacs, desktop, gnome, kde-plasma

Image will say all:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

When I maximize emacs in GNOME, KDE or other DE, I has this strange line at side of emacs window. How I could remove that line?

PS. In windowed mode all ok with any emacs window size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can.

This is due to the character-driven nature of the Emacs interface (even when windowed). Basically, the main view's width can only vary by full character width increments, not pixel-by-pixel.

When the window is maximized, the view expands to as much multiples of the character width as it can (counting space allocated for the newline margins on the left and the right), and the remaining pixels are left as free space (the band on the right you want to get rid of).

Comment: Seems that you are right. Even in windowed mode I can't change size of emacs window smoothly.